# Properly initialize a map[string]interface struct

Tags: go, struct, composite-literals

I have the following struct:

```
type InstructionSet struct {
    Inst map[string]interface{}
}
```

In the `Inst` map I'd like to put something like

```
Inst["cmd"] = "dir"
Inst["timeout"] = 10
```

Now I'd like to initialize it directly from code, but I'm not finding the proper way to do it

```
    info := InstructionSet{
        Inst: {
            "command": "dir",
            "timeout": 10,
            },
    }
```

In this way I get an error saying `missing type in composite literal`. I tried few variations, but I can't get the proper way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says the type is missing in the composite literal, so do provide the type:

```
info := InstructionSet{
    Inst: map[string]interface{}{
        "command": "dir",
        "timeout": 10,
    },
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CEGuMqSetB1).

Answer (score 2):

Composite literals have to be declared using the type of the literal:

```
info := InstructionSet{
        Inst: map[string]interface{}{
            "command": "dir",
            "timeout": 10,
            },
    }
```